# How do you release tensor variables from GPU memory in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, session.close() is not freeing the GPU memory from my model variables. I'm building and running several graphs in sequence and without fail I get an out-of-memory exception in the GPU after running several graphs, even though I'm closing the session after each run and resetting the default graph.

Using Session.reset('') solves this problem as it actually releases the variables. The problem is that reset() will also close all active sessions. Is there a way to release variables like reset() does but without closing all sessions?

Comment: Could you share an example of your code which results in this error?

Comment: I have the same issue in C++ using tensorflow...

Here is my question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652479/how-to-reuse-tensorflow-after-cudadevicereset-in-c