# How to reuse tensorflow after cudaDeviceReset() in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gpu

I am working on a large CUDA app in C++ that runs various models and needs to completely release all GPU memory or the other operations will fail.

I am able to release all the memory after closing all tf sessions and running cudaDeviceReset(), but afterwards I cannot run any new tensorflow code and session creation will return nullptrs. I tried cudaDeviceSynchronize() before and after thinking that would help, but I had no luck.

I figured the call to InitMain would reinitialize tensorflow, but it seems not to if I call again after the reset. Is there a specific entry point I can call to basically "start over" and have TensorFlow once again able to use the GPU and produce sessions?

I'm using C++, not Python. Below is an example showing what TensorFlow shows after I run the cudeDeviceReset() and then attempt to open a new TensorFlow Session in C++.

```
2018-10-04 17:01:19.225505: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-10-04 17:01:19.326074: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-10-04 17:01:19.326091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-10-04 17:01:19.326095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-10-04 17:01:19.326215: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9446 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-04 17:01:19.326554: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:785] failed to memset memory: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
2018-10-04 17:01:19.326593: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:154] Failed precondition: Failed to memcopy into scratch buffer for device 0
```

It may be related, but the first run has extra lines at the beginning as if a one time initialization perhaps has ran. The second run lacks those lines. Below is what the first looks like.

```
2018-10-04 17:01:17.253809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-10-04 17:01:17.254173: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6325
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 9.76GiB
2018-10-04 17:01:17.254185: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-10-04 17:01:17.413712: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-10-04 17:01:17.413733: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-10-04 17:01:17.413737: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-10-04 17:01:17.413888: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9446 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

I have at least figured out how to release the memory properly and nvidia-smi shows my application drop the memory as expected after the reset, but it's still not useful if I can't do anything afterwards.

I had a question about which code I'm using to establish the session. I am not using any custom session options.

```
tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions());
```

A basic reproduction is to simply load a graph into a session, close the session and graph, free the pointers, call cudaDeviceReset() and again try to open another session which will throw nullptrs and the above error messages.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up working around this by forking a child, using shared memory to communicate, and forcefully killing the subprocess as soon as I needed the memory back.

Really sad something so crippling is unacknowledged and half the github issues mentioning it are not only closed but locked to contributors only. Seems they don't want to deal with this and intentionally will not be fixing it.